# How to define amount of Slots - Kong API Gateway upstream - Roud Robin / Slots and Weight

Tags: algorithm, load-balancing, kong

I'm currently setting up an upstream with two targets.

Kong by default sets `10.000` slots in an upstream.

For what I understand, when kong is creating a upstream it creates a "wheel" with X slots (by default `10.000`).

What goes in this wheel is the target address based on its weight.

Is it correct?

If is it correct, in my case with only 2 targets, why not create an upstream with only 2 slots?

And how can I define the right weight for each upstream? Let's keep in mind that I have only two targets:

target_a
target_b

If I want to send 30% of the traffic to target_b, and given that I have only 2 slots, its weight should be 0.6?

So it will be
target_a = weight = 1.4
target_b = weight = 0.6

Is this idea right?